Delete flask_caching cached data when post request
I have a get and post request in my flask app that allows me to get data and write data to my database. I am using flask_caching and redis to cache my requested data. However I want whenever new data is added using the post request to delete all cached data related to that specific route and which match a specific pattern: "flask_cache_/api/v1/repositories/ports/*".
How to retrieve these keys in flask using flask_caching and delete them inside my post request?
Thanks
